# Mount folder with cifs share with nfs on another server

Tags: linux, mount, samba, nfs, cifs

I have the following scenario:

I have a folder `/bla/` on a server which mounts a windows samba share into it. Now I want to mount this folder `/bla/` on another server with nfs.

That should look like:

Server A:
`/bla/FoldersFromSambeShare`

Server B:
`/mnt/bla(FromServerA)/FoldersFromSambeShare(MountedOnServerA)`

I mounted the `/bla/` folder on server A but I don't see the samba folders. I tried it with the `nohide` option in `/etc/exports` but I still don't see them.

Has anyone any advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFS will not "forward" mounts. If the real file system is on `systemW`, you can have a remote mount `systemW -> (cifs) systemA`, and if `systemW` has an NFS implementation (either not Windows, or Windows with add-on software), you can also have a remote mount `systemW -> (nfs) systemB`. However, as you've noted, trying to mount `systemA -> (nfs) systemB` gives you the (probably empty) directory from `systemA` upon which `systemA` has something else mounted. Your idea to have `systemW -> (cifs) systemA -> (nfs) systemB` cannot work, at least with NFS. There are some other options if you really need to chain remote mounts (like `sshfs` and some other FUSE-based file system types).